# Django specific URL pattern for default link

Tags: python, django

I have a question regarding default URL patterns in Django

Say in my **urls.py** I have a configuration like

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^/students/(d+)/$', 'schoolapp.views.liststudents', name='list_students'),
]
```

The objective for the digit is a page-based view so `/students/1/` is first page (1st - 100th student) while `/students/2/` is second page (101th to 200th student)

Now I intend to link to this from my main page:

```
<a href="{% url 'list_students' %}">List students</a>
```

When I refresh the page, Django throws a NoReverseMatch exception with no patterns found.

Did I do something wrong? Very new to URL patterns!

Comment: As an aside, you probably don't want the leading slash. It should probably be ``^students/...``, not `^/students/...`

Answer (score 1):

You forget to put `\` before `d`, `\d` matches any digit character where unescaped `d` would match a literal `d` only.

```
url(r'^/students/(\d+)/$', 'schoolapp.views.liststudents', name='list_students')
                  ^
```

Comment: He also needs to specify the parameter in the `url` tag.

Comment: @C.B. as he specified in his question the parameter is the page number.